# mostrar primer valor (option) de una etiqueta select en angular 4

Tags: html, angular

hola estoy haciendo un formulario en el dual tengo diferentes etiquetas select que tieen valores de ciudades a las cuales quiero colocar el primer valor de options para que cuando el usuario elija se vea como primer valor el primero de la etiqueta options, el problema es que cuando integre angular la etiqueta select se me muestra en blanco y quiero que me muestre el pimer option.

aqui el codigo de mi select

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="ciudad" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="inputforShop" name="ciudad" required   >
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Quito">Quito</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Guayaquil">Guayaquil</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Manta">Manta</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Portoviejo">Portoviejo</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Cuenca">Cuenca</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Machala">Machala</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Ibarra">Ibarra</option>
                                    <option class="placeholder" value="Ambato">Ambato</option>
                            </select>
```

Como puedo mostrar el primer valor de option en mi etiqueta select?

Comment: Porque no usas el selected ejemplo:   <option value="2" selected>Quito</option>

Comment: de esa manera por defecto te cargara la ciudad deseada

Comment: eso ya lo intente y no funciono :(

Comment: otra forma es usando jquery: $("#id_select").val($("#id_select option:first").val());

Comment: para esto debes definir un id en tu select y cn esto siempre x defecto se auto seleccionara la primera option de tu select

Comment: o si deseas con javascript:  document.getElementById("id_select").selectedIndex = "0";

Comment: el cero que esta entre comillas indica que se selecionara la primera option

Comment: no te olvides de definir tu id

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que estas usando `[(ngModel)]="ciudad"` la opcion que tenga `selected` se ignorará. Angular inyectará en la plantilla el valor de `ciudad` en todo momento.

Tienes varias opciones, la más fácil es en el código de tu componente.ts darle el valor inicial 
 a `ciudad`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

   let ciudad = 'Quito'; // <= Darle valor inicial a ciudad

   constructor() {}
}
```

Angular tomará ese valor y lo inyectará en el `<select>` de tu plantilla html.

Comment: eso debe ir dentro de la etiqueta select o de la etiqueta option.
saluos

Comment: Tiene que ser en tu codigo del componente, no en tu un html. Ya actualizé la respuesta para ser clara.

Comment: @GerardoGutiérrez si pude ser de ayuda puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta  :)